# C# - TreeView erro ao popular com tabelas de base de dados SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, join, treeview

Estou com um problema e necessito de ajuda. 
Quero popular uma treeview com dados de uma base de dados SQL, mas estou com um erro ao colocar os dados através do código ele duplica tudo. 
Minha query:

```
select 
   MLSGn01.BarGroup as dep,
   MLSGn01.MenuDesc as n01, 
   MLSGn01.Id, 
   MLSGn02.MenuDesc as n02,
   MLSGn02.Id 
from dbo.[SAMECA - P_Q_$MenuListSamecaGest] as MLSGn01
left join dbo.[SAMECA - P_Q_$MenuListSamecaGest] as MLSGn02 on MLSGn01.Id = MLSGn02.ParentID 
where MLSGn01.ParentID = 0"
```

Código:

```
`           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, log.connNAV);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["dep"].ToString());
                node.Nodes.Add(dr["n01"].ToString());
                node.Nodes.Add(dr["n02"].ToString());

                treeView_menus.Nodes.Add(node);
            } `
```

Erro: 
Sendo "dep" = GroupVendas 
Sendo "n01" = Orçamento 
Sendo "n02" = Orçamento Manutenção / Preços Custo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Objetivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: quais dados são retornados na query?

Comment: de qualquer forma, a minha resposta de ontem resolve em parte isso aí. Lembre-se de marcar como resposta se te ajudou, e se tiver dificuldades acesse o [tour] pra ver como a comunidade funciona.